# MySQL how to reuse Alias to create Alias

Tags: mysql

I am facing problem of Alias in MySQL,I have a database call 'Table_Profit' and this is my query and it works fine:

```
$sql="SELECT *,
Profit*24 AS 'Daily_Profit',
Profit*30*24 AS 'Monthly_Profit',
from Table_Profit;
```

But now I want to add another Alias(Total_Profit)by using other Alias and it doesn't work, how can I solve this problem?:

```
$sql="SELECT *,
Profit*24 AS Daily_Profit,
Profit*30*24 AS Monthly_Profit,
Daily_Profit*Monthly_Profit AS Total_Profit
from Table_Profit;
```

I have try to use Derived table but it doesn't work.

```
$sql="SELECT *,
Profit*24 AS Daily_Profit,
Profit*30*24 AS Monthly_Profit,
from (
select 
  Daily_Profit*Monthly_Profit AS Total_Profit
from Table_Profit
)AS P;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A derived table is one way to do this, but you have yours backwards, because you define the aliases on the outside instead of on the inside.  Try this version:

```sql
SELECT *, Daily_Profit*Monthly_Profit AS Total_Profit
FROM
(
    SELECT *, Profit*24 AS Daily_Profit, Profit*30*24 AS Monthly_Profit
    FROM Table_Profit
) t;
```

But in this case, I would probably avoid the subquery and just repeat a small amount of logic:

```sql
SELECT *,
    Profit*24 AS Daily_Profit,
    Profit*30*24 AS Monthly_Profit,
    (Profit*24) * (Profit*30*24) AS Total_Profit
FROM Table_Profit;
```